# How to subtract two consecutive rows in MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

A table looks like:

```
id    | location | datetime
------| ---------| --------
CD123 | loc001   | 2010-10-21 13:30:15
ZY123 | loc001   | 2010-10-21 13:40:15
YU333 | loc001   | 2010-10-21 13:41:00
AB456 | loc002   | 2011-1-21 14:30:30
FG121 | loc002   | 2011-1-21 14:31:00
BN010 | loc002   | 2011-1-21 14:32:00
```

Assume the table has been sorted by ascending datetime. I am trying to find the elapse (in seconds) between two consecutive rows **within a location**.

The result table is supposed to be:

```
| location | elapse 
| loc001   | 600  
| loc001   | 45
| loc002   | 30
| loc002   | 60
```

Since the `id` is randomly generated, it is difficult to write something like `a.id = b.id + 1` in a query. And only rows within the same location is consecutively subtracted, not across different locations.

How should I write a query in MS SQL Server to accomplish it?

Comment: add a "new id" with a row_number sorted by datetime. with that you can do the "a.id = b.id + 1" you wanted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQL Server 2012 and later you can use `LEAD` or `LAG`

```
SELECT 
   location,
   SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, DateTime, 
                Lead(DateTime, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY location ORDER BY DateTime))) Elepase 
FROM 
    tableName  
GROUP BY 
    location
```

Comment: you cannot do a `GROUP BY location` when you do a `OVER(PARTITION BY location ORDER BY DateTime)` not to mention `GROUP BY` will only get you 1 row per location which is not what OP requires.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance to `LEAD` and `LAG` function. I found a tutorial about the two function (http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/lead-and-lag-functions-in-sql-server-2012.html) quite useful.

Comment: I get the desired result without `sum` and `group by` in your answer. As @ughai said, I do not understand the use of `sum` and `group by`. Would you mind give a short explanation? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
with Result as 
(Select *, ROW_NUMBER() Over (order by location,datetime) RowID from table_name  )
Select R1.location,DATEDIFF(SECOND,R2.datetime,R1.datetime)   from Result R1     Inner join Result R2 on (R1.RowID=R2.RowID+1 and R1.location=r2.location)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

Add a new [Row number column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734(v=sql.110).aspx) and then self join this on the ID e.g. [NEW ID] = [NEW ID] - 1. You can then do the subtraction i.e. Table1.[New ID] - Table2.[New ID]

Use the [LAG function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256(v=sql.110).aspx) which is a shortcut for the above method. As long as you are using SQL2012+

Answer (score 0):

Create `cte` and use `lead` to get  datetime and   next_datetime at same row.
Then calculate with `datediff` using this cte

```
WITH cte
    AS
    (
        SELECT location
        ,      datetime
        ,      lead(datetime,1) OVER (patition BY location ORDER BY datetime asc) next_datetime
        from tbl)
    SELECT location
    ,      datediff(ss,next_datetime,datetime) Elepase 
    FROM cte
```

Comment: Mind to [explain your solution](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) a bit?

Comment: Avoid code only answers. provide some description about how this works. you should be partitioning based on `Location` and not `datetime`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
  select s.location,
         s.datetime,
         datediff(ss, s.datetime, s.prev_datetime)
    from (
           select location, 
                  datetime,
                  lead(datetime) over (partition by location order by datetime ) prev_datetime
             from Table1 
         ) s
   where s.prev_datetime is not null
order by s.location, 
         s.datetime desc
```